# Find the roots of the polynomials $\pi(\lambda) = \lambda^{16}-10^{-16}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots, characteristic-polynomial

The solution (at least it claims) is
$$0.1e^{\frac{2\pi kj}{16}}, k=0,1\dots, 15.$$

How do they find this?

Graphing on Desmos it seems that upwards parabola shape seems to hit the origin at $-0.1$.

Comment: You should bear in mind those are complex numbers...

Comment: This is correct. @EeveeTrainer

Comment: In general the roots of $x^n-a^n$ are $x=a\zeta$ as $\zeta$ ranges over the $n$th roots of unity. You can get this by writing $x^n=a^n$ then writing $x$ and $a$ in polar form.

Comment: @runway44, as the usual $x = r\cos \theta \implies (r\cos\theta)^n = a^n$?

Comment: Sure, the letters "$x$, $r$, $\theta$" are conventionally used in polar coordinates so that $x=r\cos\theta$. That's a thing you do in many classes and such. But that's not what's going on here. The roots of this polynomial are complex numbers, and complex numbers $z$ have polar forms $z=re^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ (let's use the letter $z$ now I guess since that's more conventional for complex numbers).

Comment: Ok, that's right. sorry :( @runway44

Comment: @runway44 So we take $z^n = (r(\cos \theta + i\sin\theta)^n = a^n \implies r^n = \frac{a^n}{(\cos \theta + i\sin\theta)^n}$. Then I am not sure where to go from here. I am sure this is a concept that is well studied. Do you have a reference to refer me to so I don't waste your time on a trivial problem?

Comment: @Seong Write it as $\,\left(10 \lambda\right)^{16}-1=0\,$ and lookup [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#General_definition).

Comment: I like using the fundamental theorem of algebra here with thr factor theorem. There are at most 16 distinct roots and you have 16 distinct roots so that is all of them.

Comment: Ah yes @dxiv, after reading up on roots of unity and an accompanying theorem (that is easily proven) giving the n-th roots, I can easily just use the formula. Thank you!

Comment: @dxiv Your comments can solve questions✌️

Comment: @I_don't_know_maths_ Sometimes all it takes is a nudge in the right direction, and a solution worked out on your own is more enlightening than one served on a plate.